# Reading glsl code from file won't work

Tags: opengl, glsl

I start to create a Qt OpenGL application. And I followed the tutorial from [Learnopengl](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Hello-Triangle) In this tutorial, it gives the a static C-String corresponding to the vertex and fragment shader. When I give to my application a static C-String shader there is no error and my triangle appears in the screen.

But when I try to process all shader code to separate files, I have an error during the glLinkProgram command such as ***must write to gl_Position***

Here is my C++ code:

```
#include "widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QOpenGLWidget *parent)
: QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
   this->setWindowTitle("Learning OpenGL");
   QString pathV="shaders/main.vert";
   QString pathF="shaders/main.frag";
   vertexShaderSource=loadShader(pathV);
   fragmentShaderSource=loadShader(pathF);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}
void Widget::initializeGL()
{
  this->initializeOpenGLFunctions();
  qDebug()<<"Vous travaillez sur une OpenGL version:"<<QString((char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION));
  compileShaders();
  glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

}
void Widget::paintGL()
{

   GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f
   };
   GLuint VBO,VAO;
   glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
   glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
   // Bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex   buffer(s) and attribute pointer(s).
   glBindVertexArray(VAO);

   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

   glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // Note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the currently bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind

   glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO (it's always a good thing to unbind any buffer/array to prevent strange bugs)
   // Draw our first triangle
   glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
   glBindVertexArray(VAO);
   glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
   glBindVertexArray(0);

 }
 QString Widget::loadShader(QString &path)
 {
    QFile file(path);
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    QString lines;
    while(!stream.atEnd())
    {
       lines.append(stream.readLine()+"\n");
    }
    //lines.append('\0');
    file.close();
    return lines;
 }
 void Widget::compileShaders()
 {

     /* //Static shaders
     // Shaders
     vs = "#version 330 core\n"
      "layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
       "void main()\n"
       "{\n"
        "gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
       "}\0";
    fs = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 color;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "color = vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);\n"
    "}\n\0";

    //*/
    //Vertex shader
    GLuint vertexShader;
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    vs=vertexShaderSource.toStdString().c_str();
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1,(const GLchar **) &vs, 0);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    //check if any error during compilation
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success)
    {
       glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
       qDebug()<< "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog ;
   }
    else qDebug()<<"compile vertex ok";
   //Fragment shader
   GLuint fragmentShader;
   fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
   fs=fragmentShaderSource.toStdString().c_str();
   glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1,(const GLchar **)  &fs, 0);
   glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    //Check if any error during compilation   
   glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
   if(!success)
   {
      glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
      qDebug()<< "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog ;
   }
   else qDebug()<<"compile fragment ok";

   shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
   glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
   glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
   glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
   glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
   if(!success) {
      glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
      qDebug()<< "Linkage error\n" << infoLog;
   }

}
```

When I display on the console the data I read from shader files it is the same as the static C-String shader code.

So I don't see why my shader files crush.

Comment: Has it occurred to you that loading a file line-by-line is probably slower than just loading the file all at once? `QTextStream` even has a convenient function called `readAll`, which does exactly what it sounds like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

> ```
> fragmentShaderSource.toStdString()
> ```

Results in a temporary copy of the string. That temporary will be destroyed after the expression that generates it. So when you call `c_str()` on that string, you're getting a pointer to memory that is about to be deleted.

Instead, your `fragmentShaderSource` and similar vertex shader types should just be `std::string` itself. As such, `loadShader` should return a `std::string` (returning `lines.toStdString()` instead of just `lines`).

Once done, you can take `fragmentShaderSource.c_str()` and freely pass that to OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

Your shader source seems to be empty or invalid. Most probably its due to the fact that you're assigning a temporary copy a buffer to vs/fs variables:

```
 vs=vertexShaderSource.toStdString().c_str();
 fs=fragmentShaderSource.toStdString().c_str();
```

These pointers will probably be invalid right after these lines, so passing them to glShaderSource function might not be the best idea.

You have to copy buffer contents. Try something like this:

```
char* vs = new char[vertexShaderSource.size() + 1];
strcpy(vs, vertexShaderSource.toStdString().c_str());
```